# Shape of a droplet of mercury in a weak uniform electrostatic field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, geometry, surface-tension

If a droplet of mercury with radius $R$ floats in zero gravity and if it is placed into a weak homogeneous electric field $E_{0}$ it will slightly elongate in the direction of the field lines. How can I determine the equilibrium shape of the droplet?

Assumption-The surface tension of mercury is $α$, then let $ε_{0}E_{0}R≪ α$.

Attempt at a solution:
I have tried to model the electrostatic case into the Laplace equation with an electric potential, but am unable to find the shape dynamics of such a case as described in the question.

> [image: enter preformatted text here]

Comment: @CountTo10 thanks for the compliment! I don't understand why this has a tag of homework and excercises, I asked this cause this is a question that fascinated me and not something that I was assigned to do...

Comment: The tag was (probably) added because this is an "exercise" - ie a calculation. It makes no difference what the motivation is. ... Where did you get the problem from? What is the reasoning behind the assumption $\epsilon_0 E_0 R \ll \alpha$?

Comment: @sammygerbil my friend and I were having a conversation about zero gravity and he told me this problem which was asked as an interview question at a world-class institute last year. The interviewer asked my friend's brother this and gave a hint(the assumption that I have given). I asked the brother and he told me that he couldn't answer it and the question apparently has its roots in some Russian physics Olympiad of the 80's. This is all I know.

Comment: The inequality basically shows that the electric field applied is not strong enough to rip the droplet apart.

Comment: @Lelouch so could the droplet possibly assume the shape of a torous or an oblate cone?

Comment: The shape should be more of an ellipsoid, i believe, but i cannot prove it yet. I will try to work on it .

Comment: Why should it have an equilibrium shape?

Comment: @sqykly since the condition mentioned is that the surface tension must be greater than a quantity that has the dimensional formula of potential, the drop would assume an equilibrium shape

Comment: @NaveenBalaji surface tension forces the drop to have a particular ratio of surface area to volume, but there are many shapes that satisfy the requirement.  The initial shape has a gradient of potential energy across its volume in the field, and that energy has to be preserved.  Also, surface tension is a force, so I think that if the drop is not initially in its lowest energy shape, it can't reach said state without the excess energy becoming kinetic.  A stable equilibrium shape at rest requires the kinetic term to converge to 0; otherwise it should oscillate, right?

Comment: @sqykly yes it does. So I guess that makes the question even clearer, I.e., the mercury droplet's KE converges to 0 due the reason that the force gradient on its surface is much greater than that of the potential applied. Check this out for a water drop in space:https://youtu.be/gTqLQO3L4Ko

Comment: Oh by the way, i just happened to find out that this is a problem from the Rudolf Ortvay Competition (2015 or 2016), I don't remmembet

Comment: @Lelouch yep our professor gives us problems that do not have available solutions online, hence he avoids taking questions from IPHO's and gives problems from non convectional competitions.

Comment: This is a late response. First, the droplet shape is an ellipsoid since electric field creates  pressure gradient that elongates in its direction. Since $\varepsilon_0 E_0 R \ll \alpha$, elongation is very small. Elongation of semi-major axis be $a = R + x$ while semi-minor be $b = c = R - \frac{x}{2}$. Use Young-Laplace with radius of curvature defined at $R_{\text{major}} = \frac{b^2}{a} + a$ and $R_{\text{minor}} = \frac{a^2}{b^2} + b$. Taylor expand this pressure difference and then equate to electrostatic tensile stress $\sigma_{E} = \frac{9}{2}\varepsilon_0 E^2$ to derive parameters.